# Clearing cache when version changes using oclazyload

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

I am using oclazyload in my angular app, also I am setting version in my app. So whenever version number changes I need to clear the cache. is there any method to implement that?

```
angular.module('app')
    .run(['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
          $rootScope.appVersion = 1.5;
        }])

    .config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            debug: false,
            events: true,
            modules: [{
                    name: 'isotope',
                    files: [
                        'assets/plugins/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js',
                        'assets/plugins/jquery-isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js'
                    ]
                }
           ]
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the files with the version timestamp like this:

```
files: [{ type: 'js', path: 'assets/plugins/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js?v=' + version }]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use 'cache' parameter. The parameter cache: false works for all native loaders (all requests are cached by default by the browser). If you use it, the loaders will append a timestamp to the url in order to bypass the browser cache:

```
$ocLazyLoad.load({
 cache: false,
 files: ['testModule.js','bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js']
```

});

reference : [angular ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/oclazyload-service)